# extending a gem's functionality for my local copy

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I use the webdriver-user-agent to resize an automated browser easily, and it has user agents and window sizes configurable in a YAML file. I want to add to the YAML file, and I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. I may have additions that only I'll want to use, so I'm ruling out a pull request on Github, and I don't want to add it under the gem's lib directory, because then I will lose my work when I upgrade the gem.

What's the best way to add additional code to a gem?

Comment: Which gem is this? The answer will vary based on how they're loading the yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're talking about adding *configuration* to the gem, which is less easy than adding code, but still doable.

You're going to monkeypatch whatever it is that the gem uses to load its YAML configuration to instead load the configuration of your choosing. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent/blob/master/lib/webdriver-user-agent/devices.rb) you can see that the YAML is being loaded by `#devices` and the filename comes from `#devices_file`. Fortunately for us (though not so much for performance), the loaded YAML isn't cached so just replacing `#devices_file` will do what you want:

```
require 'webdriver-user-agent'
module Webdriver
  module UserAgent
    module Devices
      def devices_file
        File.expand_path("../my-devices.yml", __FILE__)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will look for a file called `my-devices.yml` in the same directory as the file the above code is in (like your spec_helper.rb or whatnot) - adjust appropriately.